# Extracting Lagrange Multipliers from SVM output in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I would like to extract the alpha lagrange multipliers from the `SVM` function in the `e1071` R package, however I am not sure if `svm$coef` is producing these?

- Alphas are defined as in Equation 9.23, p352,  [An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20Sixth%20Printing.pdf)

In the documentation for `SVM`, it says that

`SVM$Coefs` = **The corresponding coefficients times the training labels**

Could someone please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$coefs produces `alpha_i * y_i`, but as `alpha_i` are by definition non-negative, you can simply take absolute value of coefs and it gives you Lagrange multipliers, and extract `y_i` by taking a sign (as they are only +1 or -1). This is just a simplification, often used in SVM packages, as multipliers are never actually used - only their product with the label, thus they are stored as a single number, for simplicity and efficiency, and in a case of need (like this one) - you can always reconstruct them.